# Set the Lead First Name and Last Name on class Name field when student Name is blank

Tags: formula

I have  formula field class name which fetch the mentor first name and last name+ student first name, last name which have lookup related to contact. Now, if student firstname and last name is null then it will fetch lead firstname and lastname which is lookup field related to lead. Here's what I tried so far:

```
IF( AND ( ISBLANK(Student__r.FirstName),ISBLANK(Student__r.LastName) ), 'Mentor' + " " +Mentor__r.FirstName + " " +Mentor__r.LastName+" "+ 'and'+" " +'Student'+ " " + Lead__r.FirstName + " " + Lead__r.LastName + " "+ "-" +" "+ 'class start time:' +" "+Text(CreatedDate), 'Mentor' + " " +Mentor__r.FirstName + " " +Mentor__r.LastName+" "+ 'and'+" " +'Student'+ " " +Student__r.FirstName + " " + Student__r.LastName + " "+ "-" +" "+ 'class start time:' +" "+Text(CreatedDate) )
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Hi Martin, i am confused how to use If conditon in that

Comment: What's the name of the lookup field related to the lead?

Comment: IF( 
AND 
( 
ISBLANK(Student__r.FirstName),ISBLANK(Student__r.LastName) 
), 
'Mentor' + " " +Mentor__r.FirstName + " " +Mentor__r.LastName+" "+ 'and'+" " +'Student'+ " " + Lead__r.FirstName + " " + Lead__r.LastName + " "+ "-" +" "+ 'class start time:' +" "+Text(CreatedDate), 

'Mentor' + " " +Mentor__r.FirstName + " " +Mentor__r.LastName+" "+ 'and'+" " +'Student'+ " " +Student__r.FirstName + " " + Student__r.LastName + " "+ "-" +" "+ 'class start time:' +" "+Text(CreatedDate) 
)

Comment: I have tried this and its working

Answer (score 0):

The contact last name is a required field in Salesforce. Your formula is not working because the condition first name and last name are null can't be reached.

So you just have to remove the check on the last name:

```
IF( ISBLANK(Student__r.FirstName), 'Mentor' + " " +Mentor__r.FirstName + " " +Mentor__r.LastName+" "+ 'and'+" " +'Student'+ " " + Lead__r.FirstName + " " + Lead__r.LastName + " "+ "-" +" "+ 'class start time:' +" "+Text(CreatedDate), 'Mentor' + " " +Mentor__r.FirstName + " " +Mentor__r.LastName+" "+ 'and'+" " +'Student'+ " " +Student__r.FirstName + " " + Student__r.LastName + " "+ "-" +" "+ 'class start time:' +" "+Text(CreatedDate) )
```